# Function that returns the size of the memory location occupied by variable c++

Tags: c++, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am studying for an exam I have next week and am having troubles understanding Dynamic memory allocation. I have a question given which I dont know how to answer;

**line 4:** int *arr = new int[3];

Write a function that includes the line 4 above and returns the size of the memory location occupied by variable arr. **Use the signature:**

*int size_of_variable_star_arr() ;*

I assume I should be using both a main.cpp and a function.cpp - the main file should contain the array variables, while the function file should contain the array that returns it.

Not entire sure what to do here though in order to return the size of the memory location.

```
 //Main.cpp
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
//int *arr = new int[3];

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2; 
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;

cout << "Array: ";
}


 //function.cpp
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int size_of_variable_star_arr(){
 int *arr = new int[3];
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Err that's a very weird assignment, are you sure that you're being asked to write a function that dynamically allocates an array of some hard coded size and returns that size? If so, it's easy enough, just... bizarre `int foo( int*& bar ) { const int size = 3; bar = new int[size]; return size; }`

Comment: @George Yes the question I provided is the exact question. I kind of understand what you've provided...however it asks me to follow the signature so I couldn't create the foo function with a pointer could I?

Comment: If your signature is the one mentioned, you should `delete[]` the array before returning, since the allocated memory will have no more pointer pointing to it, and except through a global variable, you will not be able to communicate the pointer to the caller. And the allocation will be lost. And by default, there is no GC in C++.

Comment: the size, in bytes, is `3 * sizeof(int)`

Comment: You should make use of the `sizeof()` function. It is built-in without any header. Eg. `int size = size of(*arr);` will give the size of the `int` datatype.

Comment: @Alexander Moshos, well it's up to you I guess, you'll have a memory leak if there's no way to access the `new`'d array outside of `size_of_variable_star_arr` (and it's not cleaned up).

Comment: Actually, @OlivierSohn, no. On a system with 4-byte integers and 8-byte alignment requirements for those integers, that would not be so.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes, I agree that theoretically this is possible. And I'm curious : do you know if such system exist?

Comment: @OlivierSohn: no, it's just that I mostly prefer to code to the standard rather than any specific implementation. What if someone invents an architecture that has that behaviour as well as running a thousand times faster than anything else. My code will port immediately while everyone else is trying to fix theirs - I'll make a fortune :-)

Comment: @OlivierSohn `sizeof arr` is `sizeof(int *)`. `arr` is an `int *`. `sizeof *arr` is `sizeof(int)`. There is **no portable way** of getting the factor of 3 out of `arr`, that information is gone

Comment: @Caleth it's gone unless you know what number of elements you allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **really** strange question, but here's the answer anyway:

```
int size_of_variable_star_arr() {
    int *arr = new int[3];
    delete [] arr;
    return sizeof(arr);
}
```

Notes:

- I added `delete []` to undo the (unnecessary) `new`
- It returns the size of variable `arr`, as stated in the question. **Not** the size of the memory block which `arr` points to.

Comment: I didn't know the sizeof method existed, thankyou for enlightening me on how it can be used. This subject is run by people who barely speak english so that must be why these questions are strange.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Let me fix that for you: This subject is run by people who barely know C++ :-)

Comment: @AlexanderMoshos: If that's the case, then maybe they ask for the size of the memory block, which `arr` points to (that would be a little bit more logical to ask). In that case, the solution will be different, so if you need the solution for this case, please ask a new question.

Comment: @geza Regardless of which question they were referring to, I think the main concept here is understanding the delete and sizeof methods, which I seem to know well enough thanks to you :) Thankyou for the help all!

Comment: @AlexanderMoshos: no problem :) Just to be absolutely sure that you understand `sizeof`, `sizeof(arr)` returns the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the memory block it points to. So, no matter how big array you allocate at `new int[...]`, it will return the same value: the size of a pointer, which is typically 4 on a 32-bit, and 8 on a 64-bit compilation.

Comment: @AlexanderMoshos: and a plus information: your program has a bug. `new int[3]` allocates space for 3 elements, yet to write into 4: writing to `arr[3]` is undefined behavior.